# I would like to know how to best write the following query in oracle sql dialect

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

This is a tricky problem.  How would I query (sql oracle dialect) the following table, let's call it (Table 1) so that the output is (Table 2).

(Table 1)

| Name1 | Name2 | Value | Binary | Date1 | Date2 | Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 | Y | 1/1/2001 | 3/31/2001 | xyz |
| B | A | 15 | Y | 2/1/2001 | 2/28/2001 | xyz |
| A | B | 5 | Y | 1/1/2001 | 1/31/2001 | xyz |

Some details about (Table 1).

- Date 1 = is always the 1st day of a particular month.
- Date 2 = is always the last day of a particular month.
- Date 1 to Date 2 for a particular record can be 1 month or 2 months or 3 months in duration but never more than 3 months and no less than 1 month.
- Value = Always a positive number

(Table 2)

| Start Date | End Date | Name1 | Name2 | Value | Binary | Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 1/31/2001 | A | B | 15 | Y | xyz |
| 2/1/2001 | 2/28/2001 | B | A | 5 | Y | xyz |
| 3/1/2001 | 3/31/2001 | A | B | 10 | Y | xyz |

More comments below..
Date1, Date2 in (Table 1) are start and end dates so if (Table 1) only contained the first row, it would be presented in the format of (Table 2) in the following manner

| Start Date | End Date | Name1 | Name2 | Value | Binary | Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | Jan 31 | A | B | 10 | Y | xyz |
| Feb 1 | Feb 28 | A | B | 10 | Y | xyz |
| Mar 1 | Mar 31 | A | B | 10 | Y | xyz |

The objective is to take the records in Table 1 and "net" them out.  Row 1 in Table1 has Name1 = A and Name2 = B.  Row 2 has Name1 = B and Name2 = A.  It helps to think of this as a ledger for who owes money to each other.  A owes B in row 1, $10.  In Row 2, B owes A $15.  The "net" is that B owes A $5 but only for the month of Feb.  In row 3, A owes B $5 + the $10 from row 1 since row 1 implies a 3 month strip and row 3 in Table 2 represents the "net" owed "only" for the month of March.

Comment: Please clarify (focus on) the actual question, which is about generating rows in Table 2 from Table 1.  Strip out all the rest of the detail.  Explain each row of Table 2 (your required result) and how it is derived from Table 1 (the input).

Comment: The first row in Table 1 appears to violate requirements.  `Date2 = '3/1/2001'` is not the last day of a month.

Comment: Hi Jon.  I corrected the question.  Table 1 Date2 should be last day of month 3/31/2001.

Comment: Explain **each row and each column value** in Table 2 completely.  Why is it in the expected result?  Something is missing in your question and you still have all the unnecessary discussion about B1 and C1 and value adjustment.  That seems to have nothing to do with the question and nothing to do with your expected result.  This isn't answerable until you clarify.

Comment: Yes, the last part about B1, C1..the TempTable1, that's not the "core" of the problem.  Let's put that aside for now and I will focus on explaining Table 2 outputs and how they are calculated.

Comment: The first two rows of Table 1 have different names.  How would anyone know which rows represent overlapping detail vs. rows which are independent and should not be combined?  1) Add all this detail to the question.  Any information required to explain the question needs to be in the question.  2) Are you saying you want a query that processes every single row of Table 1 to generate Table 2 **and** the names are immaterial?  What if the property value changes?  Which value would you show?  This all needs to be in the question.  Columns which are immaterial to the question should be removed.

Comment: What does this mean?  __Records in Table 1 can "net" each other out if the Name1 and Name2 are the same but flipped as in Name1 = A, Name2 = B for one record and Name1 = B and Name2 = A.__   This usually means they negate each other and no data should be shown, or one value is subtracted from the other.

Comment: Maybe it's best if you focus on one question at a time, instead of asking about 6 different behaviors at once, each of which need to be explained.  Pick one aspect for which you are having trouble.  Attempt the problem.  Show your attempt.  Provide the input, actual output of your attempt and the expected output.  Suggestion: Start with the date range requirement, where you want a row in Table 1 with a multi-month range to be applied to every month in the range and to produce a row in Table 2 for each of those months.

Comment: Hey Jon, I can't explain it any better.  Thanks for trying.  I've cut out most of the original question as it was a bit wordy and confusing.  Whatever is there now should suffice.  Hopefully someone will get it and reply.  :)   Thanks.